# Backend data load problems

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, asynchronous

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: by error you are facing I can only tell that you are using await key word outside the async function which is illegal . Its hard to tell the exact cause of your error without looking your code . Always add code in your question its helpful ...

Answer (score 0):

You can add async at the beginning of your function.

```js
async function example() {
    const response = await doSomethingAsync();
    console.log(response);
}
```